# How can I obtain a Reliable Unique ID per Browser tab?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have several ASP.NET pages that store an object in the session and use it for data binding etc. The object in the session is referenced in several pages of a 'wizard'.

I want users to be able to have several tabs open and work on several different objects stored in the session at the same time.

I am using a URL param to do this, where the param is incremented each time the page is hit, i.e:

```
http://server/MyPage.aspx?action=1
http://server/MyPage.aspx?action=2
```

And my session access is simply

```
return (MyObject) Session["MyObject" + Request.Params["action_id"]]
```

This is fine, *but it doens't work for object data sources when they are data bound* - the error is "Request is not available in this context"

How can I get an ID that I can retrieve on the server side reliably in callbacks and page loads? The ViewState doesn't seem to be available in

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the trick is to use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request
```